# Difficulty with problem 3.11(d) in An Introduction to Statistical Learning (ISLR) (simplifying an equation)

Tags: regression, machine-learning, self-study, mathematical-statistics

I'm working through *An Introduction to Statistical Learning* and am getting stuck on question 3.11(d) from the third chapter. In short:

> For the regression of Y onto X without an intercept, the t-statistic for $H_0 : \beta = 0$ takes the form $\hat{\beta}/SE(\hat{\beta})$, where $\hat{\beta}$ is given by $\hat{\beta} =  (\sum_{i=1}^nx_iy_i)/(\sum_{i'=1}^nx_{i'}^2)$, and where
>   $$SE(\hat{\beta}) = \sqrt{\frac{\sum_{i=1}^n(y_i - x_i\hat{\beta})^2}{(n-1)\sum_{i'=1}^nx_{i'}^2}}$$
>   Show that the t-statistic can be written as
>   $$\frac{(\sqrt{n-1})\sum_{i=1}^nx_iy_i}{\sqrt{(\sum_{i=1}^nx_i^2)(\sum_{i'=1}^ny_{i'}^2)-(\sum_{i'=1}^nx_{i'}y_{i'})^2}}$$

Here is as far as I've gotten:
$$\frac{\sum_{i=1}^nx_iy_i}{\sum_{i'=1}^nx_{i'}^2}\times\sqrt{\frac{(n-1)\sum_{i'=1}^nx_{i'}^2}{\sum_{i=1}^n(y_i - x_i\hat{\beta})^2}} 
= \frac{(\sqrt{n-1})\sum_{i=1}^nx_iy_i}{\sqrt{\sum_{i'=1}^nx_{i'}^2}\sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^n(y_i-x_i\hat{\beta})^2}}
= \frac{(\sqrt{n-1})\sum_{i=1}^nx_iy_i}{\sqrt{\sum_{i'=1}^nx_{i'}^2(\sum_{i=1}^ny_i^2-2\hat{\beta}\sum_{i=1}^nx_iy_i+{\hat{\beta}}^2\sum_{i=1}^nx_i^2)}}
= \frac{(\sqrt{n-1})\sum_{i=1}^nx_iy_i}{\sqrt{\sum_{i'=1}^nx_{i'}^2\sum_{i=1}^ny_i^2-2\sum_{i'=1}^nx_{i'}^2\frac{\sum_{i=1}^nx_iy_i}{\sum_{i'=1}^{n}x_{i'}^2}\sum_{i=1}^nx_iy_i +\sum_{i'=1}^nx_{i'}^2\frac{(\sum_{i=1}^nx_iy_i)^2}{(\sum_{i'=1}^nx_{i'}^2)^2}\sum_{i=1}^nx_i^2}}
=\frac{(\sqrt{n-1})\sum_{i=1}^nx_iy_i}{\sqrt{\sum_{i'=1}^nx_{i'}^2\sum_{i=1}^ny_i^2-2(\sum_{i=1}^nx_iy_i)^2 +\frac{(\sum_{i=1}^nx_iy_i)^2}{(\sum_{i'=1}^nx_{i'}^2)}\sum_{i=1}^nx_i^2}}$$

And now I don't know where to go. I especially don't know where the $y_{i'}$ terms came from. Did I do something wrong with the indices along the way? I'd appreciate any help!

Comment: You've almost finished.  In the third term in the denominator square-root, you can now cancel out the sum-of-squares of the $x_i$s, and then the result reduces to the desired equation.  (Remember that the notation for an index value is arbitrary, so the objects are the same, even though they denote their indices as $i$ and $i'$.)

Comment: I guess then I'm getting confused about when the indices are relevant and when they aren't. If I can just switch $i$ and $i'$ back and forth, then why does the solution include separate $i$ and $i'$s? Could they all just be $i$? I've been assuming that the index values were different for a reason.

Comment: Try writing out the sum using ... notation and you will see what happens to the index.